# Finding particular value in multivalue parameter

Tags: sql-server

I am making a report in ssrs.I am sending a multi value parameter(comma separted) called @partnerAlias in a report query. Depending on whether the parameter(@PartnerAlias) contains a particular value called 'none' or not, my query will change.How can i find whether a particular value is there in multivalue parameter using SQL so that i can put condition in query.
I am new to SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-valued parameters in Reporting Services work just like subqueries, so you can do this sort of thing:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE 'none' IN (@partnerAlias)
```

Likewise the `IN (@partnerAlias)` clause could be in an `IF` statement outside of the query:

```
IF 'none' IN (@partnerAlias)
    SELECT ...
ELSE
    SELECT ...
```

Comment: Thanks @Matt. I am able to get my query working. I am only hoping for some optimisation so that I don't end up writting the entire select statements over again. Let me explain my scenario in this fashion. What I try to achieve is 
Select * from Table1 join Table2 on(condition) leftJoin Table 3 on (condition)
Now IF 'none' in (@partnerAlias) (where myStatement1) else (where myStatement2)
group by () orderby ()
Will it be feasible to put a CASE on the multivalue parameter 'partnerAlias' to prevent duplicacy of the statements with IF

Comment: How about: WHERE ('none' IN (@partnerAlias) AND <condition>) OR ('none' NOT IN (@partnerAlias) AND <other-condition>)

Comment: Thanks Matt.That will help. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
Select * 
from Table1 
join Table2 on(condition) 
left Join Table 3 on (condition) and (('none' in(@partnerAlias) and myStatement1) or  ('none' not in(@partnerAlias) and myStatement2))
group by ()
orderby ()
```